# ipython notebook - memories disappear after running some function

Tags: python, memory-leaks, ipython, jupyter-notebook

After runing some (imported) function that returns a variable, say X. The memory usage increases much more than the size of X. And even I `del X` or all variables by `%reest`. The memory usage is still much larger than before running the function. And I can only clear all memory by restarting the notebook.

I am confused, it seems the notebook saves the local variables used only inside a (imported) function? Which seems unnecessary for me. And if this is not a bug, how can I trace those large (local) variables used only in the called function, and clear those memories?

Comment: If you are referring to the *process memory size*, then there's not much you can do about it. Most in-process memory managers are only designed to *reuse* released memory, not return it to the OS's pool.

Comment: @PeterRowell yeah I mean the memory usage of ipython notebook process. But I don't see why. The variables inside a function are local, after running it, shouldn't the memory be freed?

Comment: Does this happen with any function, or is it a specific function you're running?

Comment: @ThomasK it seems any function can do it, you can try something like np.ranom.random(1e8) plus an exception within the function, some memory will be taken "forever" by the notebook, and next time you run the same function or the one without exception, you can't even reuse the memory it takes. Seems dead memory to me.

Comment: You mean a function [like this](https://gist.github.com/takluyver/1b753bc89f5b4f32c0859657c0adf7b5)? I can reproduce that. The exception is the key - Python stores the traceback from the last exception, which includes local variables. In IPython, you can jump into a post-mortem debugger for the last exception with `%debug` to examine them. If I raise another exception and then call `gc.collect()`, memory usage drops again. I can reproduce it in a plain Python shell as well, so it's not specific to IPython.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in your comment above, you are wondering why the iPython notebook process doesn't release memory back to the OS. The answer is somewhat complicated, and goes to the heart of how memory is managed in both the OS and in the process.

When a process asks for more memory, the OS has to find an appropriately sized chunk to map into the process's address space -- let's say 8KB (although it is probably some large multiple of that). This is always done on page-boundaries because of a number of factors, including how virtual memory works. TLDP has a fairly decent description of how and why this is done: [Chapter 3 Memory Management](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/mm/memory.html)

Meanwhile, the process didn't actually want 8KB for a new object, it only wanted 128B. So it gets the 8KB chunk and adds it to the in-process pool of available memory. Note that this is normally a portion of the process's address space that is contiguous so that the 8KB boundaries of the OS page are invisible to the process.

The in-process memory manager then allocates 128B to be used by whoever asked for it. This happens over and over as objects are created. When they are destroyed, the memory is returned *to the in-memory pool of available memory.*

So if it's free, why not give it back to the OS? Well, for one thing it's almost certainly not on a page boundary, so the OS wouldn't know what to do with it. It's also almost certain that the freed memory is not at *the end* of the in-memory pool. So releasing it would create a discontinuity in the pool's address space, which could then become a major PITA for the in-process memory manager to tip-toe around.

In certain circumstances, where you *know* you need some big chunk of memory, that it will be used in a way that is independent from the rest of the in-process memory management, and that when you're done with it you *can* give it back to the OS, then it is possible to reduce the process's memory size. This is most often seen when a file is [mmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap)'ed into the process image, worked on, and then unmapped. But that's special case stuff.

Comment: It seems to me, some of those not "returnable" memory is not even reusable according to a simple experiment I did: run a function with np.ranom.random(1e8) plus an exception, some memory will be taken "forever" by the notebook, and next time you run the same function or the one without exception, the memory usage will be much more than the first time you run it, i.e. it can't reuse the "lost" memory.

Comment: @chentingpc: "lost memory" is a really vague concept. Unless you have looked at the code and understand how it maintains its state, you really don't know what is "lost". I have only played with iPython, but I do know that the notebook seems to maintain a great deal of state, and that can translate to a lot of memory. I guess the question is: is this preventing you from getting your work done? If yes, then you need to delve deeper. If no, have a cookie and get on with your life. :-)